# 50s movie: octopus-like aliens take over people's bodies

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, space

I recall watching a science-fiction movie from the 1950s when I was small and I am 72 years old now.

The premise of the movie was that these aliens, that looked like small octopus, would land on people's heads and take over their bodies. I have looked all over the 1950s/60s science fiction movies and can’t seem to find the title of that movie.

Is there such a movie  and if so, what was its name?

Comment: Can you remember anything else, e.g. American/British/other?

Comment: Any chance it was the Outer Limits, Corpus Earthling? The creatures seem to be multi-legged (maybe looked like an octopus to a kid) https://i.pinimg.com/originals/50/df/7c/50df7c0158b20bd83f006341a0ec00c3.gif

Comment: Also, did they stay on the head?  So taken over humans were obvious because they had octopi on their heads?  Or did they move somewhere else later?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Sounds like the 1952 horror comic story "The Brain Bats of Venus", drawn by Basil Wolverton.

Answer (score 6):

This reminded me of the Robert A. Heinlein story, [**The Puppet Masters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters).  There wasn't a movie version of the novel itself in the 1950s ([1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters_(film))), but [**The Brain Eaters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_Eaters) covered the same basic plot in 1958.

I don't find much in the way of images of the aliens in that movie, but here's an image:

[image: Image from Brain Eaters movie]

Source:  [Rebeat](http://www.rebeatmag.com/fantasia-obscura-brain-eaters/).

I did not see this movie, so I'm not claiming that it had octopi in it.  But apparently it did have parasitic mind control.  It is unclear to me if the aliens sufficiently resembled octopi from a child's point of view.  I'm not sure what parts of the image are supposed to be the aliens.

Comment: The aliens in The Brain Eaters movie are small, furry puffs that attach themselves to the back of someone's neck. They were also created by a mad scientist, not from space.

Answer (score 0):

Could be [*Not of This Earth*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050778/)  - 1957

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve this answer by describing how this matches the details of the question.  You might want to read [answer].